# Different Regex element in htaccess REQUEST_URI Explaination?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, request

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to understand every component of this one

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/(web/.+|index.php|robots.txt)$
```

I do understand that we take the URL and if it's equal to `/main/` , `/main/web/index.php/` or `/main/web/robot.txt` we will execute the RewriteRule

However I have a hard time understanding what `%` before `REQUEST_URI` and every regex elements in `.+|index.php|robots.txt` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a hard time understanding what `%` before `REQUEST_URI`

`REQUEST_URI` is the Apache server variable. The `%{...}` "wrapper" is simply the syntax used to access the value of that server variable in this context.

> ... and every regex elements in `.+|index.php|robots.txt` means.
>
> ... and if it's equal to `/main/` , `/main/web/index.php/` or `/main/web/robot.txt`

Actually, it's not equal to either of those. The subpattern `(web/.+|index.php|robots.txt)` is regex *alternation*. It is an "OR" construct. It matches either one of the subpatterns separated by the pipe (`|`) symbol.

So, the following regex:

```
^/main/(web/.+|index.php|robots.txt)$
```

Matches either:

- `/main/web/<something>` - The `<something>` is denoted by the `.+` regex (1 or more of any character, except newlines).
- `/main/index.php` - Although the dot (`.`) in the regex matches any character. So, this could also match `/main/index-php`, `/main/indexAphp` etc. etc. The dot should be backslash escaped in the regex to match a literal dot. eg. `index\.php`.
- `/main/robots.txt` - The same comment as above with regards to the unescaped dot in the regex.

Note that in this case the entire `CondPattern` (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) is prefixed with `!` - this negates the entire expression. So, the directive is *successful* when the regex does *not* match. In other words, when the requested URL-path (`REQUEST_URI`) is *not* one of the URLs mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining to me, I understand now !